# Compare and count the frequency of pairs of entries in two columns

Tags: r, compare

I have two columns (`v5 & v6`) in a matrix where both columns have entries between `0` and `5` as

```
head(matrix)
       v1 v2  ...  v5     v6
[1,]               0      5
[2,]               1      3
[3,]               2      1
[4,]               4      1
[5,]               2      2
```

I want to construct a new (6*6)matrix contains the number of occurrences of each pair of values in both columns as

```
new_matrix
 
    0      1    2    3    4   5
0  2326  2882  2587 734  341  0
1   50  17  103 14  0   6
2     ......
3     .......
4     ......
5     .......
```

I mean that I want to know how many pairs `(0,0) , (0,1), ..., (0,5),... (5,5)` are in both columns?

I used `library(plyr)` as

```
freq <- ddply(matrix, .(matrix$v5, matrix$v6), nrow)
names(freq) <- c("v5", "v6", "Freq")
```

But this will not give the needed result!

Comment: `table(matrix$v5, matrix$v6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org), you can arrive at this answers using usual `group_by` operations.

## Sample data

I'm creating column names to make it easier to convert to `tibble`.

```
set.seed(123)
M <- matrix(sample(0:5, 100, TRUE),
            sample(0:5, 100, TRUE),
            ncol = 2,
            nrow = 100,
            dimnames = list(NULL, c("colA", "colB")))
```

## Solution

```
library("tidyverse") 

as_tibble(M) %>% 
    arrange(colA, colB) %>% 
    group_by(colA, colB) %>% 
    summarise(num_pairs = n(), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = colB, values_from = num_pairs) %>% 
    remove_rownames()
```

### Preview

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
   colA   `0`   `1`   `2`   `4`   `5`   `3`
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     0     4     4     4     2     4    NA
2     1     2     2     4     6     2    NA
3     2     6     4    NA     2     6    NA
4     3     2    NA    NA     4     6     2
5     4    NA     2     6    NA     2     4
6     5     6     2     4     4     2     2
```

### Comments

You have asked:

> I mean that I want to know how many pairs (0,0) , (0,1), ...,
> (0,5),... (5,5) are in both columns?

This answer gives you that, the question is how important is for you to have your results stored as a matrix? You can convert the results further into matrix by using `as.matrix` on what you get. Likely, I would stop after `summarise(num_pairs = n(), .groups = "drop")` as that gives very usable results, easy to subset join and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `table`

```
table(as.data.frame(M))
```

-output

```
# colB
#colA 0 1 2 3 4 5
#   0 4 4 4 0 2 4
#   1 2 2 4 0 6 2
#   2 6 4 0 0 2 6
#   3 2 0 0 2 4 6
#   4 0 2 6 4 0 2
#   5 6 2 4 2 4 2
```